# The infinite series $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty I_k(a)\operatorname{sinc}(k\phi)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

While trying to solve the differential equation
$$
a \frac{\partial^2y}{\partial a^2} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial a} -a y = e^{a\cos\phi}\sin\phi\;\;\;,\;\;\; y(0,\phi) = \phi
$$

during a calculation I was doing, I found an intriguing infinite series form of the solution:
$$
y(a,\phi) = \phi\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty I_k(a)\operatorname{sinc}(k\phi).
$$
This looks like the kind of thing that would have a "known" form, but no amount of massaging seemed to get Mathematica to give an answer (the above is in fact the result of said massaging--the initial form was much more complicated). Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: So essentially, the right side is odd-symmetric and periodic, thus can be expanded as a Fourier sine series, then you extract a factor $ϕ$. However, as the left side is not symmetric under time reversal, the particular solution will have sine and cosine terms.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Ah, I probably should have included the boundary condition.

Comment: This now makes more sense, the left side is now trivially even symmetric in $ϕ$. The equation is now inhomogeneous of Bessel kind for fixed $ϕ$.

Comment: Well, the simplest form I see is $y(a,\phi)=\int_0^\phi e^{a\cos\theta}\,d\theta$.